# How to efficiently pick a line on a grid which passes through certain points

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose I have a 30 x 30 grid and four (x,y) coordinates on them which represent goblins.

I want to place a line that is 1 x 10 wide and long that passes through as many goblins as possible.

What is an efficient way that gets you one answer?

It was too expensive to test every combination of source to target line so I need something that gives me a decent answer, doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: Take any two of the four goblins and connect them with a line.  If you get the 3rd or 4th goblin also, that's a bonus.  Since you can only draw six lines over four goblins, two at a time, you can test all six lines and see which line is the best fit.

Comment: genius, I like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add some details on @GilbertLeBlanc answer:

"Take any two of the four goblins and connect them with a line."

If you choose them randomly:

1. if no three are on the same line, then you have the best answer;
2. if all four are on the same line, then you have the best answer;
3. if three are aligned and one is not, your probability to get the best answer is 1/2.

All in all, already quite good.